# UIKit: Constraints on a UITableViewCell don't work properly for the first few cells in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

I have the following `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FlagListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ReusableView {
    private let flagImageView = UIImageView()
    private var cellHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.cellHeightConstraint = self.flagImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        self.cellHeightConstraint.isActive = true
                
        self.flagImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.flagImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.contentView.addSubview(self.flagImageView)
        
        // Constraints the top, leading, trailing, and bottom anchors of `flsgImageView` to `self.contentView`
        self.flagImageView.pinEdges(to: self.contentView)
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func bind(to country: Country) {
        let image = UIImage(named: country.flagImageName)!
        self.flagImageView.image = image
        
        let imageViewWidth = self.contentView.frame.width
        let imageWidth = CGFloat(self.flagImageView.image!.cgImage!.width)
        let imageHeight = CGFloat(self.flagImageView.image!.cgImage!.height)
        
        let scaledHeight = imageHeight * (imageViewWidth / imageWidth)
        self.cellHeightConstraint.constant = scaledHeight
    }
}
```

I have a `UITableViewController` subclass which displays ~250 of these cells (as reusable cells).

When I display the table view however, the first three cells (or however many the device screen size fits) have incorrect constraints for some reason and cause the cells to look incorrect. However, for all other cells, they look fine. Additionally, when I scroll down and then back up to the first three cells, they look fine as well.

Anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?

I have tried the following solutions, and none have worked:

- Implementing the `heightForRowAt` delegate method and returning `UITableView.automaticDimension`, and also implementing the `estimatedHeightForRowAt` delegate and returning various values for it
- Implementing `layoutSubviews` method for the table view cell class to update the constraint, and then calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`.

Here is a screenshot of the cells with the incorrect constraints:

[image: broken cells]

And here is a screenshot of the cells working as intended:

[image: correct cells]

**Edit**:
I call `bind(to:)` in the table view's diffable data source's cell provider:

```swift
    private lazy var dataSource: FlagListDataSource = {
        let source = FlagListDataSource(tableView: self.tableView, cellProvider: self.cellProvider)
        source.viewModel = self.viewModel
        return source
    }()

    private func cellProvider(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, countryId: Country.ID) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(FlagListTableViewCell.self, for: indexPath)
        let country = self.viewModel.country(id: countryId)
        
        cell.bind(to: country)
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: When do you call `bind(to:)`?

Comment: @Sweeper I added an edit to the Bottom of my post detailing when I call it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a conflict in how you're setting constraints for your `flagImageView`; you're activating a height constraint for it, but then you're also pinning all four of its edges. And you're setting the content mode to `.scaleAspectFit` but it seems like what you actually want is `.scaleAspectFill`.

Try these 2 changes in your init and see if that works.

```
self.cellHeightConstraint.isActive = false
self.flagImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```